# Getting an SVG element to expand to fill an anchor element

Tags: css, svg

I'm wondering whether there is a way to fit an svg element inside an element (Something like setting width and height to 100% causing it to fill up the anchor element)?  I have a [pen](https://codepen.io/oleersoy/pen/EWRKva) that I'm experimenting with, however ATM the only way I can get the svg element to overlap the anchor element precisely is to set the height of the svg element.

```
svg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; 
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;    
   width: 100%; 
   height: 45px;
}
```

I was hoping that setting `top, bottom, left, right` all to zero would snap it in place inside the anchor element.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,900);

.btn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 45px;
  max-width: 560px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-1 {
  background: #df2822;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.btn-1 svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
.btn-1 rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 422;
}

.btn-1:hover {
  background: rgba(225, 51, 45, 0);
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


body {
  background: #E1332D;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-1">
    Hover
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to support IE or don't want to use `object-fit` then you could also change your HTML to:

```
<a class="btn btn-1">
    <span>Hover</span> <!--adding a span tag-->
    <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Then your CSS can simply be:

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;   
    width: 100%; 
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tymothytym/pen/ryKgaQ).

Comment: Awesome!  Will that work in general for all elements when I want to completely fill the parent container?  I'd like to make a `u-fill-container` (Better name?) utility that can be applied to any element.

Comment: I'd guess that if the internal element is an inline-element (like a span or p) or you specifically style it to be one then yes, but I kinda stopped experimenting when the span worked so that's theoretical!

Answer (score 4):

set the svg's css to this

```
svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that `object-fit` is currently unsupported by all versions IE (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectposition/)

Comment: Thanks - I did a stack snippet answer trying it out and it works.  I'm running in chrome though.  Would be great to have a cross browser solution.

Comment: See my answer below for cross-browser solution

Answer (score 1):

You kind of answered your own question. Yes, setting width & height to 100% will make it fill the anchor.

Altho, on your pen you had to place it over it because it was more to the left and lower. The reason for that is simply because in the anchor you place text before your svg, thus moving it.

Also, since it's the svg that get place and not the rect, there was some redundant html.

I made it work in your pen with this code:

html:

```
<a class="btn btn-1">
    <svg>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
        <p>Hover</p>
    </svg>
</a>
```

css:

```
svg {
    position: absolute;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

*the text wouldn't show when not in a container, hence the p tag.

---

1st edit: atho, tru, leaving it before but in a span tag does do it.

---

2nd edit: (your question made me experiment more)
The reason the svg wouldn't align is because your text was not in a tag. So as long as you don't let ''free'' text, any tag could be used when setting 'display: flex'. (if you wanted your text to be a button for say)

If not using flex, then you can put your text in a span/p tag in the svg OR you can leave it before but make its position absolute and then place it with right:%/top% or transform.

Comment: @ole I can't comment other people's answer yet but I wanted to answer your question in comment ''Will that work in general for all elements when I want to completely fill the parent container?''

If you mean, instead of a svg, any other element then yes. Using this method would fill the parent container.